# failed bundle install and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a virtual machine (ubuntu) on windows and bundle install and bundle update keep failing.

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ sudo bundle update

Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler  
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run': ERROR: \ 
  Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)`
```

Comment: show `Gemfile` you're there gems version?

Comment: `bundle update` resolve dependencies from scratch, ignoring the `Gemfile.lock` Resolving all dependencies from scratch can have surprising results, especially if a number of the third-party packages you depend on have released new versions since you last did a full update.

Comment: please show all the log

Answer (score 0):

can you update the qsn with the Gemfile?

It means, some the gem dependencies are not present. Check which gem requires dependency and use `sudo apt-get install library-name`  to install that. Also bundle commands should not be run with sudo as it will create issues. try to keep it project specific and not at root level.